# COMException was unhandled

Tags: c#

I am using `c#` to build a small test project which will scan a image .Here is my code to do that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WIA;
namespace Scanner
{
    public class Scanner
    {
        Device oDevice;
        Item oItem;
        CommonDialogClass dlg;
        public Scanner()
        {

                dlg = new CommonDialogClass();
                oDevice = dlg.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);


        }
        public void Scann()
        {
            dlg.ShowAcquisitionWizard(oDevice);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
       // [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
           Application.Run(new Form1());
       }
    }
}

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Scanner oScanner = new Scanner();
            oScanner.Scann();
            button1.Text = "Image scanned";
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
```

But when I try to run the application and click the button I get the following error at this line  `dlg = new CommonDialogClass();`

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {850D1D11-70F3-4BE5-9A11-77AA6B2BB201} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80070422.
```

Can anybody suggest me what the issue here is
Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us at which line the exception is being thrown? Attach a debugger, it will help you. I guess it must be throwing my Ctor of Scanner class or Scann() method. Perhaps stepping through did not help?

Comment: @zenwalker , i edited it.Do you think it could be because the dll is not properly registered.

Comment: Are you seriously asking a question when you don't even have the scanner connected?

Comment: @Ramhound , I have it connected but it throws the same exception even if its connected or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mahaafifi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/iclassfactory-failed-due-to-following.html

"go to windows Adminstrative tools => services => WIA service => enable it and start it"

Hope this helps.

Comment: unable to find WIA service there.

Comment: do you think it could be because currently my computer doesnot have a scanner connected.

Comment: Try this: Go to service management console (Start -> Run -> Services.msc)
Make sure that the 'Windows Modules Installer' is enabled
Then check for updates.

Comment: enabled means I need to start it right ??? After that I need to do what you suggested earlier right?

Comment: I don't know. I've copied and pasted from results that seem relevant from a really quick google search. You need to search about a bit. You have the error code there which is specific enough to find your solution.